# Creating a command with sprintf. Is this possible?

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot some data. The data is in several files and the line it is in is not always the same. Therefore I used grep and some other commandline tools to extract the line I want. I read online, that it should be possible with gnuplot to print from a string or from the result of a commandline.

I work in linux.

```
set terminal pdfcairo enhanced font "Garamond,10" fontscale 1.0 size 9in,9in

set nogrid
set samples 1001
set border 31 linewidth .3
set output "access/accessTimeAcrossFreq.pdf"
set xlabel "freq"
set ylabel "Time [s]"
set key right top
set size square
set autoscale y
set termoption lw 2.5

volts = "0.8"
fins = "111 122 222"
freq = "0.5G 1G 1.5G 2G 2.5G 3G"

metrics = "read1bldeltav read0bldeltav read1senseChange read0senseChange read1latchChange read0latchChange sense1speed sense0speed write1CellFlip write0CellFLip write1CellSwing write0CellSwing write1BLSwing write0BLSwing powerpertime"

runTitle = "abetraryString"
filename(fin, f, volt) = sprintf("../%s_temp27_fin%s_freq%s_vdd%s/accessTimeVolLSA/result.txt", runTitle, fin, f, volt)

data(met, file) = system(sprintf("grep -n '%s' %s | cut -d: -f 2 | awk '{$1=$1};1'", met, file))
com(met, file) = sprintf("< grep -n '%s' %s | cut -d: -f 2 | awk '{$1=$1};1'", met, file)

do for [fin in fins] {
    do for [v in volts] {
        do for [met in metrics] {
            set title sprintf("%s VLSA across Freq, fins %s, %sV, w/o she", met, fin, v)
            plot for[i=1:words(freq)] com(met, filename(fin, word(freq, i), v)) using (i):2:xtic(word(freq, i))  notitle with points lc i
        }
    }
}
```

So I was wondering if a) I can have a function that returns a string that is a command that is then run by gnuplot
b) Where the error might come from:

```
line 32: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
line 32: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
line 32: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
line 32: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
line 32: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
line 32: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
line 32: x range is invalid
```

I thought, maybe I need a linebreak at the end of my one-liner of data. Or because gnuplot always thinks the first line is not data... I don't know.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `grep` and `awk` so I don't know what exactly you are extracting. But if you can describe your datafile structure (r give some example lines) and tell which lines or values you need to extract, and I'm confident that there is also a solution with gnuplot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I figured it out. I used prints in the for loop to see what the command returns. Before I posted the question I tried the command in a separate terminal with success. The problem was I just tested it with the first element of `metrics`. The prints revealed that I forgot the `metrics` need to be all lower case.

To conclude. Yes, you can put a string via a function together and gnuplot will then run it as I was expecting it. See the use of `com(..)` in the plot line.

Second. I think the xrange error usually points out that in a plot there are no data points and gnuplot does not like a xrange of 0. To figure this out I used prints. I did a quick search if there is a verbose mode but was not successful, so prints it is.

Maybe someone can take away something like I did.